# WAMP error 500 when attempting to setup Magento2

Tags: magento2, error, version, wamp

I'm attempting to setup my own WAMP server and use Magento 2. I've installed to my machine however in my apache error log I get

IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: your PHP and apache version ??

Comment: Apache Version: 2.4.33 
PHP Version:5.6.35

Comment: Try turning on the apache module `version_module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you need to enable the IfVersion module on the server

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

This is the missing `version_module` from apache - it will be used to check your PHP version which for Magento 2 is PHP 7, you will need to install this on your WAMP if you are using php 5 currently, or if already installed just switch to this version under the PHP versions tab.

Comment: This fixed one of the errors however i then had to double check my php version on wamp and then it was fixed. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes I said in my answer that you would have to install or change your php version :)